# what is the difference between RVR 200m and R 200m (LVO jeppesen landing minima)

Tags: landing, jeppesen

sometimes JEPPESEN approach chart shows low visibility landing minima as RVR in meter or sometimes just R in meter. What is difference….

Comment: Please provide examples of what you're referring to; it's much easier to answer this sort of question, and the information is more meaningful to others, when we can all see these expressions in context. Thanks!

Comment: What is a "jeppesen"? Is it a place, "Jeppesen"? (Capitals matter!)

Answer (score 1):

There are different cases.

1. The RVR is provided by a State authority, `State` is mentioned in the top left corner and R is used instead of RVR.

   > [image]
2. For minimums provided by [EASA AOM](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/AUG_2022_DRAFT_ATC_EASA_Aeroplanes_eff_30_Oct.pdf)

   `State` is replaced by `Std/State` (`Standard` up to 2020), and RVR is used. But:

   > For separate minimums listings (like 10-9S pages)
   > RVR, CMV and VIS are abbreviated as “R”, “C” and
   > “V”.

   [Source](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Introduction-to-Jeppesen-Navigation-Charts.pdf#page=88)
3. Since 2022, for EASA AOM:

   RVR is also abbreviated by "R", both for landing and takeoff:

   > [image]

   > Straight-in landing minimums will be shown as RVR
   > with prefix “R”, as provided within the EASA tables.
   > A Visibility, prefixed "V", will only be charted if a
   > VIS value is published as State minimum. The prefix
   > “VIS” may still be used on older charts

   > Take -off minimums are shown as RVR “R”, as VIS
   > “V” or as RVR/VIS “R/V”. Values which could be
   > either RVR or VIS may be depicted without any prefix
   > on older charts.

   > A Visibility, prefixed "V", will only be charted for take-
   > off if a VIS value is published as State minimum.
   > For separate minimums listings (like 10-9S pages)
   > RVR, CMV and VIS are always abbreviated as “R”,
   > “C” and “V”.

   [Source](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/Introduction-Pages-221-230-9-SEP-22.pdf).